# I am trying to compile xonsh from source however it doesn't seem to recognise xonsh as a command even after build and install

Tags: ubuntu, installation, xonsh

I am trying to compile xonsh from its git repository, I am using the following commands to install it:

```
git clone https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh.git
```

I then change directories into xonsh after cloning the repo, followed by the build and install:

```
sudo python3 setup.py build
```

Once I run this, a large but quite impressive text-art shell, a line saying "running build" and then the terminal prompt appears instantly, almost as if it didn't build. Regardless, I ran the following line to install it:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

And then it is showing a bunch of install lines with no errors and then it ends with "running install_scripts", then the terminal prompt shows up straight away again.

I have tried using the "xonsh" command, nothing works, it says its not found, nothing i can find in /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin that's related to xonsh.

I have tried using the "xonsh" command, nothing works, it says its not found, nothing i can find in /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin that's related to xonsh. I even tried deleting and re-installing it however no luck there.

Before anyone asks why I dont use pip install xonsh, I am trying to do it via compiling from source, so I will only resort to this if compilation deems impossible. I appreciate any help/advise given :).

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `pip` to install a Python package from source (and you should, `setup.py` usage is deprecated).

If you are in the cloned source directory you can run

```bash
pip install . --user
```

The `--user` part will install the entry-point (the `xonsh` executable) in `$HOME/.local/bin`, so make sure that is part of your `$PATH`.  Generally you want to avoid using `sudo` with your system python because it can make things go a little screwy.

Most users are better served by the prompt_toolkit-based version, so for that